# In Objective-C, how to prevent name collision in category methods?

Tags: objective-c

Some people have used prefixes to name their category methods in order to prevent possible name collisions with other external code, but I personally find that adding noise to a name that is otherwise clear.  Is there a better way to avoid category name collisions than prefixing it?

e.g.

```
@interface UILabel (Extras)
-(void)prefix_extraMethod;
@end
```

Comment: I agree. The prefixes are probably a good idea, but I refuse to use them. I'll take my chances.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Objective-C doesn't exist namespace so the only way is to prefix your method.

If don't want to prefix (I agree with you..it's ugly) you can the `OBJC_PRINT_REPLACED_METHODS` environment variable to `YES` to receive a warning if you method name collide with other existing method.

[image: set environment variable]

Answer (score 6):

Nope. Prefixes are the way to do it.

Comment: I agree with you completely, even though I'll never use them. I find them so esthetically displeasing that, simply put, I'll take my chances. I've been writing Objective-C code for many years and have never had a problem.

Comment: @GregoryHigley: I find the arrow operator ugly, but I still use it in C and C++ because it is part of the language and using it is convention (rather than using the equivalent `(*).`). Being contrarian doesn't win you any points.

Comment: The prefix should be in the file name too? Like NSString+CCDoThis.h
For example... ?

Comment: That's common practice, but it's not required by the compiler since your filenames can't conflict with already-compiled filenames.

Comment: I agree. But there is one variation that I think works nicely, which is what I've used around the office. Say you're writing some corporate app named according to some unique, oddball acronym: for example, your app's name is BEDO. I'm going to suggest that it's then safe to incorporate the app's name into category methods, instead of a prefix, in a way that makes the method name more readable.