# NSArray isEmpty

Tags: objective-c, categories, is-empty

I am creating an `NSArray` category as following:

```
//
//  NSArray+Empty.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSArray (Empty)

/**
 * Convenient method to check if the array is empty or not.
 */
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isEmpty;

@end
```

and:

```
//
//  NSArray+Empty.m
//

#import "NSArray+Empty.h"

@implementation NSArray (Empty)

- (BOOL)isEmpty {

    return (self.count == 0) ? YES : NO;
}

@end
```

then, using this category with a "`nil`" object like:

```
  if (array.isEmpty)
       return;
```

WHERE: array - parameter sent to the method

I expected that `isEmpty` is returning TRUE either for nil or empty arrays, but it returns FALSE for `nil` array.

My questions is not WHY, because I know why. My question is: is it possible to make my `isEmpty` to return TRUE even for nil objects?

Comment: As a small optimization, you could just `return (self.count == 0)` -- the `==` compare returns a bool-like value.

Answer (score 3):

As @Wain and @Michal both pointed out, messages to `nil` always return `nil` or zero so there's no way to get the behavior you're trying to achieve with a method. Instead you could write a C function:

```
// Assuming your project uses a prefix such as XYZ...

BOOL XYZIsEmptyArrayOrNil(NSArray *array)
{
    return array == nil || [array count] == 0;
}
```

Then call it like so...

```
if (XYZIsEmptyArrayOrNil(myArray)) {
    // Do whatever.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answerers have already correctly pointed out that a message to `nil` returns 0; if the method is supposed to return a `BOOL`, that 0 is interpreted as `NO`.

I'd suggest changing the semantics of your method to take advantage of this fact:

```
- (BOOL)U262IsNotEmpty
{
    return ([self count) > 0);
}
```

Don't forget that [you should always put prefixes on methods you add to framework classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466732/in-objective-c-how-to-prevent-name-collision-in-category-methods).

Answer (score 0):

If your `array` is `nil` then no message is actually sent so you can't write your method to deal with that.

If you structured your code as a function that you pass the array to instead then you could deal with the parameter being `nil`.

Answer (score -1):

Every method called on nil returns nil. nil's boolean value is false so that's why your if is not working.

To fix it, use code:

```
if (!array || array.isEmpty)
  continue;
```