# prefix header import cancels out library's implementation of same method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4

I have a category on UIView that implements `- (void)setWidth:(CGFLoat)newWidth`, that sets the width by changing the frame of the view and a static library that has the same method.
I am using the category throughout the whole project by adding it to the .pch (prefix header) file.

When I try to use the library method, my category overrides the setWidth: method and the library is never called. I don't really want to remove the category from the prefix header as that would cause serious issues with the rest of the project.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Thank you!

~LSonic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Objective-C methods (including those from categories) exist in the same namespace. If there are two method implementations with the same name, it is not defined which is called at runtime.

This is discussed in [Avoid Category Method Name Clashes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW4) in Apple’s *Programming with Objective-C*.

There is no better way than prefixing the names of methods in your categories. For example:

```
- (void)ls_setWidth:(CGFLoat)newWidth;
```

Also [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466732/in-objective-c-how-to-prevent-name-collision-in-category-methods) for more.

Comment: That would be an interesting solution apart from the fact that I have to change a few 1000 lines of code.... I have a feeling that I'm not getting out of this that easily...

Comment: Have you tried Xcode’s refactoring tools? Select your `setWidth:`, then go to Edit > Refactor > Rename. It does not always catch everything, but it is worth a try.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to do so as soon As I find time! I will reply on how it worked.